# crear distintos objetos para un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
const students = [{
  age: 32,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'male',
  name: 'edu'
},
{
  age: 29,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'female',
  name: 'silvia'
}]
```

Y necesito agregar un objeto nuevo cada vez que llame la siguiente funcion:

```
function newStudent() {
  let newStudent = new Object();
  newStudent.age = randomAge;
  newStudent.examScores = [];
  newStudent.gender = randomGender;

  newStudent.name = newStudent.gender === 'male' ? randomNameMale : randomNameFemale
  students.push(newStudent)
}
```

```
const availableMaleNames = ['pepe', 'juan', 'victor', 'Leo', 'francisco', 'carlos'];
const availableFemaleNames = ['cecilia', 'ana', 'luisa', 'silvia', 'isabel', 'virginia'];
const availableGenders = ['male', 'female'];

const randomNameFemale = availableFemaleNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableFemaleNames.length)];
const randomNameMale = availableMaleNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableMaleNames.length)];
const randomGender = availableGenders[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableGenders.length)];
const randomAge = calculateRandomNumber(20, 50);

function calculateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return randomNumber;
}
```

El problema es que me agrega el mismo objeto cada vez que llamo la funcion...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de que me cree objetos distintos cada vez que llame la funcion newStudent???

Comment: queres que agregue objetos aleatorios dentro de students? falta el codigo de randomAge randomGender randomFemale etc. A no ser que estes usando alguna biblioteca o api que te genere valores aleatorios.

Comment: Ese codigo lo escribi pero no lo agregue para hacer mas sencilla la pregunta..

Comment: si eso es lo que necesito crear objetos aleatorios

Comment: pues agregalo, ahi debe estar el problema. Mientras mas informacion des mas facil sera ayudarte.

Comment: Vale si tienes razon, ya lo agregue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacer que cada vez que quiera agregar un estudiante llame a otra funcion que genere valores aleatorios en un array, entonces usas ese array para agregar el objeto a students, el nombre que depende del genero de la persona se valida en la funcion newStudent():

```
const availableMaleNames = ['pepe', 'juan', 'victor', 'Leo', 'francisco', 'carlos'];
const availableFemaleNames = ['cecilia', 'ana', 'luisa', 'silvia', 'isabel', 'virginia'];
const availableGenders = ['male', 'female'];

const students = [{
    age: 32,
    examScores: [],
    gender: 'male',
    name: 'edu'
  },
  {
    age: 29,
    examScores: [],
    gender: 'female',
    name: 'silvia'
  }]

function newStudent() {
  let newStudent = new Object();
  let data = getRandomData(); // obtenemos el array de datos aleatorios de la funcion getRandomData()
  newStudent.age = data[3]; // age ahora tiene el valor de data[3] (un numero aleatorio)
  newStudent.examScores = []; 
  newStudent.gender = data[2]; // aca definimos el genero obtenido de data
  newStudent.name = newStudent.gender === 'male' ? data[1] : data[0] // como el nombre depende del genero, si gender es igual a male devuelve data[1], sino data[0]
  students.push(newStudent) // pusheamos el objeto resultante
}


function getRandomData(){ // funcion que devuelve un array con datos aleatorios
  let randomNameFemale = availableFemaleNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableFemaleNames.length)];
  let randomNameMale = availableMaleNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableMaleNames.length)];
  let randomGender = availableGenders[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableGenders.length)];
  let randomAge = calculateRandomNumber(20, 50);
  return [randomNameFemale,randomNameMale,randomGender,randomAge];
}
function calculateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return randomNumber;
} 

newStudent();
newStudent();
newStudent();
newStudent();
newStudent();
newStudent();

console.log(students)
```

El problema con tu codigo era que sacabas un valor aleatorio y lo declarabas como const entonces siempre ponia los mismos valores, mejor llamar a una funcion donde esos datos sean variables locales de la funcion y cada vez que la llames te genere valores diferentes.

Comment: muchas gracias tienes toda la razon estaba enfocando mal lo que necesitaba hacer...

Comment: me alegro que te haya ayudado @Emily Heredia